# ConfigurationErrorsException in TechTalk.Specflow.dll

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, xunit

When I'm trying to execute my feature file using specflow, I get an exception at

`throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Data provider section is not set.");`

which says

> Exception of type System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   occurred in project but was not handled in code

```
/// <summary>
/// Reads the configuration related to the set of configuration
/// </summary>
private static void LogInitializer()
{
    LogProviderConfiguration configSection = (LogProviderConfiguration)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("LogProviders");
    if (configSection == null)
   throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Data provider section is not set.");


    _providerCollection = new LogProviderCollection();
    ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(configSection.Providers, _providerCollection, typeof(LogProviderBase));

    _providerSettings = configSection.Providers;

    if (_providerCollection[configSection.DefaultProviderName] == null)
        throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Default data provider is not set.");
    _default = _providerCollection[configSection.DefaultProviderName];
    var defaultSettings = _providerSettings[configSection.DefaultProviderName];

    _default.SetParameters(defaultSettings.Parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have the config file in specflow project.  Please add app.confog file with LogProviders section and then it should work.